# Monte-Carlo integration of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, monte-carlo, numerical-calculus

It isn't clear to me how to tweak Monte Carlo integration to evaluate Riemann-Stieltjes integrals.

So I have the following integral over $S$ which is some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is quite large (like 20 or so).

$$I = \int_{S} g(x) dF(x)$$

In particular I'm assuming that $F$ is some distribution function for a random variable $X$. $F$ is not well behaved. Namely it might not be continuous. I can sample from $X$ but computing specific values of $F$ is hard/intractable to do directly. If the integral was just $\int_{\mathcal{S}} g(x) dx$ I could approximate the integral with $N$ samples as from *some*  distribution (e.g. not the same as $F$) with PMF $p$ (ideally $p$ proportional to $g$) with samples $x_1,\ldots,x_N$:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{g(x_i)}{p(x_i)}$$

But that doesn't account for $F$. It's not really clear to me how to tweak standard Monte Carlo integration to account for $F$ however. If we sample according to $F$ we can just use the following simple formula

$$I \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N g(x_i)$$

But if $g$ is only large on very specific values this is going to take a ton of samples to converge.

Is there any source that explains how to do this?

Comment: You need to sample points with the distribution $F$.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused. What do I do with $p$ then? $p$ is *not* the PMF of $F$. I can only sample from $F$, I can't compute it (but I sample from an approximation of $F$ that I can compute, hence $p$ being the pmf of that)

Comment: So what do you know about $F$?

Comment: Sorry, I was presuming that $F$ was a probability measure. If it is and you draw the $x_k$ with distribution $F$ then the estimate is just given by ${1 \over n} \sum_k g(x_k)$.

Comment: Jorge, I can sample from it and I can use heuristics to approximate it depending on the case. $F$ isn't fixed.

@copper.hat I guess that's certainly a way to compute an expected value but I was hoping to use importance sampling specifically.

Comment: So you can just do what copper.hat said right?

Comment: Yeah that would work but I guess I wouldn't call that Monte Carlo integration. Specifically there's no speed up based on $g$

Comment: I added a clarification

Comment: Perhaps another phrasing of this problem, is "how do I use importance sampling when I can't compute the PMF of my original distribution function"